# How to upload multiple images in a Django field

Tags: django, file-upload

I have checked many uploaders for django image field. But I am unable to get a simple clear way of doing multiple image uploads in Django.

My requirement is

```
Class Foo(models.Model):
       images = SomeImageField(upload_to = "/path/")
```

This should allow me to upload multiple images. Now **django-photologue allows Gallery upload, but this is only in zip format**. I want something similar. Is there any such app available ?

Comment: May I ask what did you end up doing? how did you resolve this. I might need to know

Answer (score 5):

[`django-filer`](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-filer) will allow you to upload multiple images via a separate interface (not via a model field, but via the django admin), but you will only be able to select one of those uploaded image per image field. What you need to do is implement a [django admin StackedInline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) or something similar

```
# models.py
from django.db import models
from filer.fields.imagefields import FilerImageField

class MyObject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class Image(models.Model):
    image_file = FilerImageField()
    obj = models.ForeignKey(MyObject, ...)

# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from models import Image, MyObject

class ImageInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Image

class MyObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ImageInline, ]

...
```

now you will be able to easily attach multiple images to a single instance of your object via the admin.

I don't know of any apps that allow for a single field to manage multiple images.